# python multiprocessing and joblib argument passing

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, joblib

I have some confusions about Python multiprocessing, when it involves global numpy array.

Consider the follow toy example, the argument passed is an integer that indicates the row to be summed. My questions are:

1. Does each processor/worker has a copy of x?
2. How does the performance change if I pass the actual row, for example, `pool.apply_async(sum, (x[i],))` and change the function sum() accordingly. My understanding is that the argument passed is a view of the numpy array, so it shouldn't affect anything in non-parallel program. But what about multiprocessing programs.
3. If I rewrite the program with joblib package, `results = joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=-1, max_nbytes=1e6)(joblib.delayed(sum)(i) for i in xrange(len(x)))` does each processor/worker has its own copy of x? if it does, since x is read-only, what is the easiest way to share across the workers?

the code:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

def sum(idx):
    """
    sum the idx row of global numpy array x
    :idx: indicate which row
    :returns: float sum 
    """
    return np.sum(x[idx])

x = np.random.random((10, 100))
pool = Pool(cpu_count())
result = {} 
for i in xrange(len(x)): 
    result[i] = pool.apply_async(sum, (i,))

for k, v in result.iteritems():
    print k, v.get()
```

thank you

Comment: In `multiprocessing`, each process is given a copy of the original data. This is contrary to `threading`, where all sub-threads are given access to the original data, and act on it directly. Performance will go up if you don't pass the entire `numpy array`, but instead pass a list of ints from the array. I'd recommend seeing http://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html for a great example of this.

Comment: hello @VDN, can you explain what do you mean by pass a list of ints ? a list of index? and where does that linked tutorial covers passing numpy array? thanks

Comment: Your sum function should be summing the actual values (a numpy array of the actual ints for that function), not a copy of the entire numpy array accessed by index.

Comment: can you please look at another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26520606/joblib-auto-shared-numpy-array-with-max-nbytes-keyword and see what is happening? thank you